# Introductory Text to Ethics

Tags: ethics

I'm looking for an introductory text into philosophical inquiry of ethics.

I need this text to be exceedingly accessible (i.e. high school or undergraduate level) but still sufficiently philosophically rigorous.

I would like to use it as a required summer reading for second year philosophy students, so it can assume some basic philosophical background, but I don't want it to be overly technical (i.e. Kantian, lol.)

I'd prefer a text that takes a survey-like approach, probably one that touches upon the three major frameworks: virtue ethics, consequentialism, and deontology.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [Introduction to Ethics](https://www.google.it/search?q=introduction+to+ethics&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj429L86f3aAhULvhQKHf4FC1MQ_AUIDSgE&biw=1366&bih=637).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Okay, I was looking for a recommendation, not an education in how to conduct a Google search.  I suspect some of the texts algorithmically suggested by Google do not meet my stated requirements.  I was hoping that, you know, someone had read one and could recommend (or recommend against) it.  But thanks?

Comment: But you can use the search result to find useful info: the author is often owner of a Wiki's entry (e.g. Bernard Williams): you can read it and have useful infos. You can browse the ToC of books and read  the Intros, to have some "feeling" about the content.

Comment: The [Very Short Intros](https://books.google.it/books?id=tKBnw7BKe-UC&printsec=frontcover) are often brief ans clear.

Comment: Yes, I am a fan of VSI.  Have you read that one on ethics or you're just recommending the series in general?

Comment: Finally, there are the On-line encyclopoedias: [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/search/searcher.py?query=ethics) and [IEP](http://www.iep.utm.edu/category/value/ethics/).

Comment: Yes, I have used those resources myself and as sources for students -- they are invaluable.  But I'm looking for a book, not an encyclopedic entry.

Comment: I can recommend Alasdair MacIntyre's A Short History of Ethics. It is an introductory undergrad text taking a historical approach, with a view to introducing a wide variety of different approaches to ethics, rather than just arguing for one theory the author prefers.

Comment: Could you follow this approach?  M. Boylan,  Teaching ethics with three philosophical novels. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-3-319-55711-3%2F1.pdf I have not read the paper, but it caught my eye.

Comment: (I see now the seller only gives a few pages, nevertheless you may want to get the book or use it as food for thought. )